# Running Windows Application after system locked

Tags: c#, windows

I have created a windows application in C# which captures windows lock/unlock status using -

```
  SystemEvents_SessionSwitch()
```

I have kept this application in continues running mode using an infinite while loop.

the problem I am facing is when the user locks the system this application also stops working and doesn't return exact status when unlocked it executes twice for the lock as well as for unlocking.

Can anybody suggest some way by which I can make this application running even after the system is locked

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your application as a windows service, that way it will always run even after system reboot if you set it to start automatically and you do not need to be logged on.

Comment: Can I covert windows application to windows serive? OR I will need to create complete new application.?